# Is XOR operator in Kotlin a feature or a bug?

Tags: java, kotlin, logical-operators, operator-precedence, xor

I've been a Java Developer for many years and recently I've found something very suprising in Kotlin. In Java there is a rarely used logical operator `^` **XOR** but sometimes it's useful. For example: you can easly check if one and only one of two numbers is greater than zero.

With `&&` **AND** operator and some variables `a` and `b` it looks like that:

```java
boolean valid = (a > 0 && b <= 0) || (a <= 0 && b > 0);
```

but it can easly achieve with `^` **XOR**:

```java
boolean valid = a > 0 ^ b > 0;
```

Now, in Kotline we don't use `^` as a **XOR** but just `xor` and same code in Kotlin looks like that:

```
val valid = a > 0 xor b > 0;
```

And here comes a problem because this code in Kotline gives ... **compilation error**!! Why? Because in Java all logical operator (`&,&&,|,||,^`) got lower precedence than relational operators (`>, >=, <, <=, ==, !=`). Same in Koltin but it looks like not for `xor`. So it goes this way:

1. `a > 0` gives boolean value
2. `boolean xor b > 0` first evealuated to: `boolean xor b` not `b > 0`
3. And finally we got compilation error that said: `The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Boolean`

You can check this situation here: [XOR not working well](https://pl.kotl.in/KocCoS6_6)

**One extra case:** if you think that this one: `a > 0 xor (b > 0)` works... well, no. Another compilation error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean but Int was expected`

**Can anyone explain me is there some purpouse for such logic or it's just a bug in Kotlin language?**

Comment: I agree with you 100% that it's a bug, but that's the way they designed it, whether deliberately or accidentally.

Comment: Parentheses are your friend.

Comment: Sounds like language design flaw.

Comment: O.O nice find!!! Agree that's weird.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`xor` is not an operator, but an
[infix](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation) function. Infix function calls have higher precedence than the comparison. [Expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions)

`val valid = a > 0 xor b > 0` is the same as `val valid = a > (0 xor b) > 0`

1. `(0 xor b)` gives Int value
2. `a > (0 xor b)` gives Boolean value
3. and it turns into a comparison between Boolean and Int (`(step 2 Boolean result) > 0`), but you cannot compare Boolean with Int

Correct version:

```
val valid = (a > 0) xor (b > 0)
```

Comment: It's absolutly clear for me how `XOR` work here :) Problem here is that `XOR` is logical operator and it SHOULD HAVE lower precednce than relational operators, especcially it has in Java. And the question is not how `XOR` works but why they decided that it works this way

Comment: Why "it SHOULD HAVE lower precedence than relational operators"? There is no comparison operators in boolean algebra. In python xor (bitwise) has higher precedence than comparison operators as well

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Because the way it is is different from every other programming language that has it.

Comment: @emka86 *"It's absolutly clear for me how XOR work here"* Then how come you wrote it wrong in the question following the *"So it goes this way"*, if it's clear to you that it works the way shown in this answer?

Comment: IMO, there's _no_ ideal approach.  XOR can be bitwise or logical; it would make most sense for the bitwise version to have higher precedence than comparison operators, but the logical one to have lower — yet it would be confusing to have an operator with difference precedence in different circumstances.  So all languages compromise on the precedence (or have different operators for the two cases).  But bitwise operators are used much less than when C was written, so Kotlin simply removes them from the language and leaves them to the standard library — with its own precedence requirements.

Comment: @DrawnRaccon , @Andreas - as i said: i perfectly understand why this is happening and what to do do get valid result. Event converting tools (from Java to Kotlin) change `a > 0 ^ b > 0` to `(a > 0) xor (b > 0)`. You wrote about bitwise operator and yes, they've got higher precedence than relationals operator like any other arthimetics/bitwise operation. But as you also said, in Kotlin, there is no bitwise operator xor. Thus lets leave bitwise operator and talk about logical operators. All other logicals operator with two operands got lower precedence than relationals so why not this one?

Comment: `xor` is not an operator, is a function that performs a logical operation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/xor.html

Answer (score 1):

xor (being an infix function-[docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation)) in Kotlin has lower precedence than the arithmetic operators(*, /, %,+, -) and has higher precedence than Comparison(<, >, <=, >=),Equality(==, !==) & Assignment(=, +=, -=, *=, /=, %=) operators.(check for full reference for precedence [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions)).